# Unable to import xgboost in Python

Tags: macos, python, import

I have installed xgboost successfully using pip for Python 2.7.16 (I installed this Python version using Homebrew on macOS High Sierra). My problem is that I'm unable to import xgboost in Python, as per the error message below:

```
mac-128644:~ user$ python
Python 2.7.16 (default, Apr 12 2019, 15:32:52) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import xgboost
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xgboost/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .core import DMatrix, Booster
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xgboost/core.py", line 163, in <module>
    _LIB = _load_lib()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xgboost/core.py", line 154, in _load_lib
    'Error message(s): {}\n'.format(os_error_list))
xgboost.core.XGBoostError: XGBoost Library (libxgboost.dylib) could not be loaded.
Likely causes:
  * OpenMP runtime is not installed (vcomp140.dll or libgomp-1.dll for Windows, libgomp.so for UNIX-like OSes)
  * You are running 32-bit Python on a 64-bit OS
Error message(s): ['dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xgboost/./lib/libxgboost.dylib, 6): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/8/libgomp.1.dylib\n  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xgboost/./lib/libxgboost.dylib\n  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:\n\t/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xgboost/./lib/libxgboost.dylib/libgomp.1.dylib: stat() failed with errno=20']
```

I've made sure that both my Python version and OS are 64-bit, so the problem is definitely not the second "likely cause." I'm also pretty sure I have OpenMP installed: looking up instructions, for my case I would do `brew install llvm` and the install was successful. I'm also not sure why it can't seem to find `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xgboost/./lib/libxgboost.dylib`, as I can `cd` into that directory and see `libxgboost.dylib` just fine. It looks like later on in the message it *did* find it, but still throws an error? What exactly is going on here, and what can I do to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed gcc?
You can try the following steps.

`brew install gcc@8`
then do

`brew switch gcc 8.3.0_2` or the version installed then finally

`brew link --overwrite gcc` this seeemed to have fixed my issue.

Comment: When I try ``brew switch gcc 8.3.0`` (the version of gcc@8 it installed) it doesn't work, it says the only gcc version I have is 9.1.0.

Comment: and the last step `brew link`?

Comment: @TedDesmond you were probably seeing this error because inside your `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc` folder you only had `9.2.0`. Try copying `8.x.x` from the `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc@8` folder and retrying these commands.

@VictorNg'eno I was able to successfully execute these commands and still had the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Your Python interpreter says you are in Python 2.7, but according to [pypi xgboost project](https://pypi.org/project/xgboost/), it requires Python 3.8 or above.